# JQuery datatable with multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, datatables, pug

So I am trying to implement multiple tabs with Datatable like in [the documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html).

From the server side, I have data like the following.

An array of sessions in number, ex: session1 session2.

For each session, it will have columns like name, age.
For now, the Datatable works if I just pass one session.

How do I implement the multi-tab datatable while passing a session array to my pug file?

I am using the JQuery Datatable with pug and the number of sessions might be different.

Here's the code that I have for now for pug file in head and body.

```
head
    title !{comp}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js')
body
    table#comp.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-bordered

    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js')
    script(src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')
    script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#comp').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: `/api/competition/#{id}`,
                    dataSrc: "session1"
                },    
                columns: [ 
                    { "title": "Name", "data" : "Name" },
                    { "title": "Age", "data" : "Age" }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call your tables via a class (or anything BUT ID) because you will be having multiple tables (tabs). In this example, your ajax data should be in the object **data** (no matter how many sessions) and just include a field for sessionID in the data (make it the last field).

```
var table = $('.datatables').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: `/api/competition/#{id}`,
                    dataSrc: "data"
                },    
                columns: [ 
                    { "title": "Name", "data" : "Name" },
                    { "title": "Age", "data" : "Age" }
                ]
            });
```

Then each tab is actually doing a search within the data:

```
$('#myTable1').DataTable().search( 'session1' ).draw();
$('#myTable2').DataTable().search( 'session2' ).draw();
```

Comment: I try this but it ends up appearing the search string(session1, session2) in the search block that datatable auto-generate.
It did show up two tables if I do two search at the end but both are the same without filtering by session.

Comment: if that is the case, you might not want to use their recommended process and instead make your own. Use jQuery to create the tabs, and inside each tab have a separate table and run databable per table instead of one single call.

Comment: You might be right. Just wondering if there's any easier implementation.